# "chron-34e2fg command consume 100% CPU on Linux AMI"

Tags: linux, cpu, malware, malware-removal

Hello i'm not the principal answer of this question, however, i want to answer at this [Original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50074683/chron-34e2fg-command-consume-100-cpu-on-linux-ami?answertab=votes#tab-top) asked at the wrong place, in fist part i said how i fix it and then i will edit this post to say where is the problem if i find:

> on server when I run top command then I am showing a process that takes 100% of CPU.

And

> `PID USER    PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU  %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND`
>
> `6267 nginx  20   0  256m 5132 1288 S 171.6  0.1   7:15.89 chron-34e2fg`

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problematic. So to solve it do this procedure.

1. Stop apache2 process : `service apache2 stop`
2. Delete malware : `rm -f /var/tmp/chron-34e2fg /var/tmp/.jnks/*`
3. Reinstall apache 2 like this [quote](https://askubuntu.com/a/746206) said

REINSTALL APACHE2:

> `sudo apt-get purge apache2`
>
> `sudo apt-get install apache2`

Then REINSTALL PHP5:

> `apt-get purge libapache2-mod-php5 php5 && apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5 php5`